# Klein's Erlanger Program

Tags: geometry, math-history

What does "Erlangen" mean in "Klein's Erlanger Program" or "the Erlangen Program". According to Translate.com, "Erlangen" means "gain," but "the Gain Program" does not seem like a reasonable name of it.

Comment: It is named after the University Erlangen-Nürnberg.

Comment: If at all, it would be the little gainer program ... ;)

Comment: See [Erlangen program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlangen_program) and Deutsch [Erlanger Programm](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlanger_Programm): "published by Felix Klein in 1872... It is named after the University Erlangen-Nürnberg".

Comment: Another name comes up here: Lie groups - "Lügen Gruppen" in German (according to Translate.com, babel.com and user109871.com).

Comment: @DietrichBurde - NO; it is from [Sophus Lie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophus_Lie).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA What else, of course! But **not** according to translating services as above.

Answer (score 4):

Erlangen (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlangen) is a town in southern Germany. Klein held a chair at the local university (now "Erlangen-Nürnberg") and published the Erlanger Program on the occasion of obtaining this chair.

(Concerning the meaning as a proper word, and the fact that the university used to be prominent in theology, there is a silly pun "Suchet das Reich Gottes zu erlangen", which may mean "Seek to reach the Kingdom of God" or: "Go to the Kingdom of God that will be found in [the Town] Erlangen" that hinges on the fact that spoken language does not distinguish upper or lower case in Erlangen/erlangen. Also the emphasis in "Erlangen" is at the first syllable while in "erlangen" it is on the second.)